# Add bootstrap icon inside input at right side

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I'm starting to work with bootstrap and I need to do the following: I have an input which I want to add two icons together on the right side, for the moment grouping them into a '`div`', but I'm going down, I'm not very good with `css` ni design so it would be very helpful to tell me how I should do it.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<input type='text' value='' class='form-control'><a><i class='fa fa-check-circle fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></a> <a><i class='fa fa-times-circle fa-2x' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

The `.input-group` class is a container to enhance an input by adding an icon, text or a button in front or behind it as a "help text".

The `.input-group-addon` class attaches an icon or help text next to the input field.

For more info xfer: [bootstrap_forms_inputs](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_forms_inputs2.asp)

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="col-lg-4">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input class="form-control left-border-none" placeholder="User Name" type="text" name="username">
    <span class="input-group-addon transparent">
    <i class='fa fa-check-circle fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>
    <span class="input-group-addon transparent">
    <i class='fa fa-times-circle fa-lg' aria-hidden='true'></i></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Another solution, you can use the combination of css property `position` & `right` to align icon at right side. Use `top` to align from top. Add right `padding` to input.

```css
.check-icon {
right:50px;
position:absolute;
top:2px;
}

.times-icon {
right:20px;
position:absolute;
top:2px;
}

.icon-input {
padding-right:60px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="col-lg-4">
<input type='text' value='' class='form-control icon-input'><a><i class='fa fa-check-circle fa-2x check-icon' aria-hidden='true'></i></a> <a><i class='fa fa-times-circle fa-2x times-icon' aria-hidden='true'></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for replying, however is not what I need, I need exactly like this in my example code, I just need to align it to the right of the input both links

Comment: @max I have added another solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<div class='input-group form-group'>
<label class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-check-circle fa-2x'></i></label>
<label class='input-group-addon'><i class='fa fa-times-circle fa-2x'></i></label>
<input type="text" value="" class="form-control"/>
</div>
```